# How to create a background task using Flask and Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celery

I am creating a web application via Flask and deployed via Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. My application has the user upload a CSV which I then process to create an output CSV that the user downloads.

My current problem is the processing takes a long time and requires the user to stay on the same page in order to generate and download the output CSV in the end.

Is there a way for the processing to take place in the background so the user can leave the page and not wait for the processing to finish? I plan to store the output CSV in S3 so the user can access the output CSV later.

I've looked at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/background-task-handling-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

and

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/

but I'm not sure how to use the information in those links to solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.